# Is this a possible implementation of Selection Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

i'd like to know, if my following implementation of SelectionSort is a possible implementation. Thank you guys! :)

```
    public static int[] mySelectionSort (int [] array){

    int position = 0;
    int tmp;

    for (int j = array.length -1; j >= 0; j--){

        int max = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){

            if (array[i] >= max){

                max = array[i];
                position = i;
            }   
        }

        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = max;
        array[position] = tmp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is selection sort variation.

You can omit last inner cycle run using `for (int i = 0; i < j` - there is no sense to exchange last item with itself.

One can consider cycle invariants:

- there are two subarrays - beginning part B and ending part E
- E contains sorted sequence
- all items in E are not smaller that items of B
- the largest item from B is concatenated with E

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the algo with some examples and it worked fine. Why position has to change? In my opinion its correct, because position saves only the position of the max element, and when the inner loop is over, the element at position j swaps with the element on position position.